# Reshaping Data into panel form

Tags: r, csv, format

I have data where the object name is a variable name like `EPS`, `Profit` etc. (around 25 such distinct objects)

The data is arranged like this :

```
EPS <- read.table(text = "
Year    Microsoft   Facebook
2001    12          20
2002    15          23
2003    16          19
", header = TRUE)

Profit <- read.table(text = "
Year    Microsoft   Facebook
2001    15          36
2002    19          40
2003    25          45
", header = TRUE)
```

I want output like this :

```
Year Co_Name   EPS Profit
2001 Microsoft 12  15
2002 Microsoft 15  19
2003 Microsoft 16  25
2001 Facebook  20  36
2002 Facebook  23  40
2003 Facebook  19  45
```

How it can be done? Is there any way to arrange data of all variables as a single object? Data of each variable is imported into R from a csv file like EPS.csv, Profit.csv etc. Is there any way to create loop from importing to arranging data in a desired format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for fun we can also achieve the same result using `dplyr`, `tidyr` and `purrr`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(readr)
library(purrr)

list_of_csv <- list.files(path = ".", pattern = ".csv", full.names = TRUE)
file_name <- gsub(".csv", "", basename(list_of_csv))

list_of_csv %>%
  map(~ read_csv(.)) %>%
  map(~ gather(data = ., key = co_name, value = value, -year)) %>%
  reduce(inner_join, by = c("year", "co_name")) %>%
  setNames(., c("year", "co_name", file_name))
## Source: local data frame [6 x 4]

##    year   co_name   eps profit
##   (int)    (fctr) (int)  (int)
## 1  2001 microsoft    12     15
## 2  2002 microsoft    15     19
## 3  2003 microsoft    16     25
## 4  2001  facebook    20     36
## 5  2002  facebook    23     40
## 6  2003  facebook    19     45
```

Comment: It would be better if you could provide some description about using `map`, `reduce` etc.

Answer (score 3):

We can get the datasets in a `list`.  If we already created 'EPS', 'Profit' as objects, use `mget` to get those in a `list`, convert to a single data.table with `rbindlist`, `melt` to `long` format and reshape it back to 'wide' with `dcast`.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.6+
DT <- rbindlist(mget(c('EPS', 'Profit')), idcol=TRUE)
DT1 <- dcast(melt(rbindlist(mget(c('EPS', 'Profit')), idcol=TRUE),
           id.var=c('.id', 'Year'), variable.name='Co_Name'), 
           Year+Co_Name~.id, value.var='value')
DT1
#   Year   Co_Name EPS Profit
#1: 2001 Microsoft  12     15
#2: 2001  Facebook  20     36
#3: 2002 Microsoft  15     19
#4: 2002  Facebook  23     40
#5: 2003 Microsoft  16     25
#6: 2003  Facebook  19     45
```

If we need to arrange it, use `order`

```
DT1[order(factor(Co_Name, levels=unique(Co_Name)))]
```

Comment: It is cool. But I want data company wise ie first for Microsoft and then Facebook.

Comment: @Neeraj You can order it

Comment: In your code Microsoft and Facebook vaules are interchanging.